# Prove $a_n=\frac{n!}{2n}$ is a divergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove $a_n=\frac{n!}{2n}$ is a divergent sequence using the definition of divergence: **A sequence $a_n$ diverges if $\forall L\in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists \varepsilon>0$ s.t. $\forall N$,
> $\exists n\gt N$ s.t. $|a_n-L|\ge \varepsilon$**

I know I'll start off with something like:

**(1)** Let $L\in \mathbb{R}$ be given

**(2)** Choose $\varepsilon=1$

**(3)** Let $N\in \mathbb{N}$ be given

I know $n!\gt n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ but I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: $n! \geq n(n-1)$.

Comment: $a_n=(n-1)!/2$.

Comment: What you actually need to prove is that for any $K>0$, there is an $N$ such that $|a_n|>K$ for all $n>N$. This means that your sequence diverges to infinity.

Comment: Your point (2) is incorrect. You have to show that some $\varepsilon>0$ exists satisfying the given property, but there is no reason for $1$ to be a valid choice of $\epsilon$. Intuitively, $\varepsilon$ would probably depend on $L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are of course shorter ways, as indicated in the two first comments, and you could even prove more, as indicated in the third one. But if we follow your method, let me first notice you are lucky that your choice $\varepsilon=1$ will work (cf. Taladris's comment).

So let us start after your point 3. We need to prove that for some $n>N,$ $|a_n-L|\ge1$ i.e. $|n!-2nL|\ge2n$ or (simplifying by $n$) $|(n-1)!-2L|\ge2.$ For this, it is sufficient that $(n-1)!\ge2+2L.$ Therefore (applying your last sentence) it suffices that $n-1\ge2+2L.$

There exists an $n>N$ such that $n\ge2+2L+1$ (the smallest is $1+\max(N,2+2L)$ but any $n\ge$ that one will do).

If you hadn't fixed $\varepsilon=1,$ you could have (less optimistically) looked if there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ playing the same role, i.e. such that $|a_n-L|\ge\varepsilon$ for an infinity of $n$'s. You would similarly have found that this happens for all $n\ge2\varepsilon+2L+1$ hence that any $\varepsilon>0$ is convenient.

Comment: Is it important that we know the *smallest* $n$? And if I didn't assume $\varepsilon=1$, should I have just continued the same process from $|a_n-L|\ge \varepsilon?$

Comment: "Is it important that we know the smallest n?"  It's not in the *least* bit important.  It is completely and totally irrelevant.  I've never understood text that concentrate on that as though it is somehow "efficient". What's most important in a proof is that it's convincing. And to me a proof that shows by an incredibly simply calculation that for an $n > N$ then $a_n$ is fivehundred gazzillion times  $\epsilon$ more than $L$ is more convincing than pages of convoluted calculations to prove that $a_n$ is *just* a teensy bit more than $\epsilon$ over $L$.